# max size of a vb.net form

Tags: vb.net

what is the maximum size of a vb.net form. So that it will consume the whole screen.

Comment: I have a web browser dragged into the form and I want the web browser to consume much of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use change the "WindowState" property. This will ensure the window is maximized independent of the screen resolution.

In code:

```
 Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You probably want to set the `WindowState` property to `Maximized`.</strike>

Alternatively, you might be looking for the [`SystemInformation.VirtualScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen.aspx) property.

**EDIT**: In response to your comment, you need to set the WebBrowser control's `Dock` property to `Fill`.  You can do this in the designer using the property grid.

Comment: You also need to learn to write precise, descriptive questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your screen-resolution, know your screen resolution, and you can resize it to that. Fortunately, you can just set `WindowState` to `Maximized` and vn.net will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programmaticaly in this way

```
  Me.MaximumSize = New Size(200, 300)
```

Hope it helps!